# Как в react делается переключение активного класса?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть список кнопок, мне нужно сделать переключение, чтобы при выборе у прошлой кнопки уберался активный класс. В самом начале первая кнопка должна быть активна.
Я знаю, что нужно это делать в стете, но стейт делать активным классом все кнопки.

Пример на react и javascript https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-wozniak-2mvdje?file=/src/App.js

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может вам лучше использовать для этого `<input type="radio">`?

Comment: Да, я тоже так думаю. Просто хочу узнать как это можно сделать, если не использовать input

Comment: Вынесите ваши кнопки в отдельные компоненты, далее в `App` создайте массив из нужного количества элементов (в вашем случае 3, например `[1, 2, 3]`). Потом там где нужно делаете самый обычный `map`. В ваши компоненты передаёте `onClickHandler` и `isActive`. В `App` создаёте стейт, который хранит в себе индекс активного элемента. Во время выполнения `map` смотрите если текущий индекс равен значению в стейте, то передаёте `isActive={true}` иначе `false`. `onClickHandler`, будет функцией обновления, например `onClickHandler={() => setActiveIndex(index)}`, где `index` берётся из `map`

Comment: Написал бы полноценный ответ, но щас занят, как освобожусь напишу с примером кода

Comment: @EzioMercer
Да, хотелось бы увидеть пример. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я уже говорил в комментариях:

- Создаём отдельный компонент, куда будем передавать функцию `handleClick` для обработки клика, булевую переменную `isActive`, которая будет отвечать за нужный нам класс элемента и строковую переменную `text`, который будет текстом наших кнопок
- Создаём стейт, в котором будем хранить индекс активного элемента
- Создаём массив `arrayForButtons` нужной длины, с помощью которого будем рисовать наши кнопки
- Проходимся по этом массиву с помощью [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) и передаём все переменные в нужном формате, значения которых зависит от индекса `i`

Код:

```js
const {useState} = React;
const {createRoot} = ReactDOM;

const MyButton = ({handleClick, isActive, text}) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick} className={`react-button ${isActive ? 'active' : ''}`}>
      {text}
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const arrayForButtons = Array(3).fill(0);  

  const javaScript = (event) => {
    const el = event.target;

    document
      .querySelector(".javascript-button.active")
      .classList.remove("active");
    el.classList.add("active");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h1>React</h1>
        <div className="group-button-javascript">
          {
            arrayForButtons.map((_, i) =>
              <MyButton
                key={i}
                handleClick={() => setActiveIndex(i)}
                isActive={activeIndex === i}
                text={'Button ' + (i + 1)}
              />
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <h1>JavaScript</h1>
        <div className="group-button-javascript">
          <div onClick={javaScript} className="javascript-button active">
            Button 1
          </div>
          <div onClick={javaScript} className="javascript-button">
            Button 2
          </div>
          <div onClick={javaScript} className="javascript-button">
            Button 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

// Rendering

const container = document.querySelector('#root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />)
```

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.javascript-button {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid #ffaa22;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.react-button {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid #bbffdd;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.javascript-button.active {
  background-color: #ffaa22;
}

.react-button.active {
  background-color: #bbffdd;
}

.group-button-javascript > *,
.group-button-react > * {
  margin: 0 auto 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как в react делается переключение активного класса?

Применительно к твоему примеру можно предложить нечто такое...

```js
function App() {
  const [btn, setBtn] = React.useState([true, false, false]);

  const javaScript = (event) => {
    const el = event.target;

    document
      .querySelector(".javascript-button.active")
      .classList.remove("active");
    el.classList.add("active");
  };

  const react = (n) => {
    setBtn(old => old.map((v, i) => i === n));
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h1>React</h1>
        <div className="group-button-react">
          {btn.map((v, i) => <Btn key={i} act={v} i={i} click={react} />)}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1>JavaScript</h1>
        <div className="group-button-javascript">
          <div onClick={javaScript} className="javascript-button active">
            Button 1
          </div>
          <div onClick={javaScript} className="javascript-button">
            Button 2
          </div>
          <div onClick={javaScript} className="javascript-button">
            Button 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
//
function Btn(props) {
  const {act, i, click} = props
  let cls = ['react-button']
  if (act) cls.push('active')
  cls = cls.join(' ')
  return <div onClick={_ => click(i)} className={cls}>
    Button {i}
  </div>

}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#like_button_container'));
root.render(<App />);
```

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.javascript-button {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid #ffaa22;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.react-button {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid #bbffdd;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.javascript-button.active {
  background-color: #ffaa22;
}

.react-button.active {
  background-color: #bbffdd;
}

.group-button-javascript > *,
.group-button-react > * {
  margin: 0 auto 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```