# Как в react получить несколько элементов?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Я сделал вывод элементов на странице

```js
{addressData.map((e, i) => 
   <div data-address={`address${i}`} className={styles.address__card}>
     <p>Время работы: {e.time}</p>
     <p>Адрес: {e.address}</p>
     <a href={`tel:${e.phone}`}>Телефон: {e.phone}</a>
   </div>    
)}
```

Теперь когда на кнопку определенную кнопку нажимают, у всех элементов должно быть opacity .5, а у нужного 1, но я не понимаю как получить все элементы, ref вставляется в массив только к 1 элементу при map. А через document.querySelector вроде не правильно делать. Как можно получить элементы address__card, чтобы им всем сделать opacity .5.

Пример:

```
const enable = (e) => {
   document.querySelectorAll(`[data-address]`).style.opacity = ".5"
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в react делается переключение активного класса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515918/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-react-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0)